# Using code (function/template) in a Vue.js application from one component in another component with no direct relationship

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-portal

I'm working on an app using Vue.js and I came across the following challenge:

The app has a pretty basic layout: a *header*, a *main* view and a *navigation* section at the bottom. Depending on the page the user is currently on I want to show a *main action* in the header. See the following wireframes:

[image: App wireframe of view 1][image: App wireframe of view 2]

**My question now is:** is there a way to "inject" the template and code into the header? Because ideally I would like to have the logic and the appearance (like an icon with label) in the corresponding component and not in the header, because it isn't aware of the current view.

The header and the main view of the components have no parent/child relation. The basic Vue.js template looks like this:

```html
<div class="app-content">
    <TheTopBar/>
    <main>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </main>
    <TheNavigationBar/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to do it...

1. Add [default slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) into `TheTopBar` template at the place you wanna see your actions
2. Remove `TheTopBar` component from your top-level component, place it inside your  "main view" components templates (each of them) and define content of the slot there (actions)

Other way could be using Vue router's [Named Views](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html) but that would require you to create separate "actions" component for each corresponding "main view" component

## Edit

Actually there is other way. [portal-vue](https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue) allows exactly what you want....

Comment: Thanks. I did read something about portal-vue a while ago, but did forget about it completely. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you cannot inject code from one component to another. You will have to have the template logic inside the `header` component.

However, there are a couple of things you can do.

1. Inside the `header` component you can check what the current path is with `this.$route.path`. And based on that display the action item. (if you are using a router)
2. Use a `vuex` store to track what the action item in the header should be. You could have the `main` component set the store value and `header` can then read it and act accordingly

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did suspect that.
I thought about various ways to achieve the desired behavior including your proposals. But I thought maybe there is a way I overlooked.

Comment: check @michal-levý answer. I had forgot about `portal-vue`. That should do the trick